# Laravel Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am getting this error in console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`, i'm using **Laravel 5.7**, here is my code of `@section()`:

```
@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            function expandTextarea(id) {
                document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('keyup', function() {
                    this.style.height = 0;
                    this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';
                }, false);
            }
            expandTextarea('textarea');
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

and here is `app.blade.php`

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('public/js/app.js') }}"></script>
@yield('scripts')
```

I tried many solutions provided on internet, but all in vain I copied this code from my other project in which it's working very well, but here it's not working.

Comment: `addEventListener` of null means, `getElementById` returned null, which means, there is no HTML element with the ID 'textarea' in blade file. Make sure the HTML tag `id='textarea'` is present on the element you are targetting.

Comment: where are you calling `expandTextarea(id)`?

Comment: @Ibu see the last fourth line of `@section('scripts')`.

Comment: assign `document.getElementById(id)` to a variable.

Comment: Working like a charm thanks... @Mysteryos write this in the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addEventListener` of `null` means, `getElementById` returned `null`, which means,

there is no HTML element with the ID 'textarea' in blade file.

Make sure the HTML tag `id='textarea'` is present on the element you are targetting.